# Law of cosines for $n$ dimensional vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors, inner-products

The law of cosine is
$$\|b-a\|^{2}=\|b\|^{2}+\|a\|^{2}-2\|b\|\|a\| \cos \theta $$

Is there a way to prove this when vectors  $a, b$ have more than 3 components?

For 3 or less components one can prove it using geometry but what about higher dimensions?

Comment: In what part of your proof do you use dimension?
You have $a\cdot b = \|a\|\|b\|\cos\theta$ in any dimension.

Comment: Are you saying that it's a given definition ? A starting point?

Answer (score 1):

In any dimension, the norm is related to the scalar product by :
$$\| a\|^2 = a\cdot a$$

and the angle $\theta$ between two vectors $a,b$ is *defined* by :
$$a\cdot b = \|a\|\|b\|\cos \theta$$

Therefore, :
\begin{align}
\|a- b\|^2 &= (a-b)\cdot (a-b) \\
&= a\cdot a - a \cdot b  - b\cdot a + b\cdot b \\
&= \|a\|^2 + \|b\|^2 - 2 a\cdot b\\
&= \|a\|^2 + \|b\|^2 - 2 \| a\|\|b\|\cos \theta
\end{align}

Comment: Is $a\cdot b = \|a\|\|b\|\cos \theta$ really a starting point. Does there exist any more basic rule from which it follows? My textbook proves $a\cdot b = \|a\|\|b\|\cos \theta$ from the law of cosines.

Comment: Well, when you first learn about euclidean geometry, angles are taken to be a primitive notion. Then you can *derive* $a\cdot b = \|a\|\|b\|\cos \theta$. The usual way to extend this to arbitrary dimension is to study vector spaces equiped with a scalar product. Here, the scalar product is the primitive notion, and  $a\cdot b = \|a\|\|b\|\cos \theta$ is the *definition* of the angle $\theta$

Answer (score 0):

This is obviously trivially independent of the dimension.. If you square the difference b-a you get the square of b minus  the square of a, minus 2 times the  the inner product of a and b.

If you want a geometric interpretation, imagine you want to find a circle circumference. You need to approximate its lenght by regular polygons whose sides you relate to the radius using the inner product and if you use cosine in its definition and take as angle to be in radians you get the correct approximation and in the limit you get 2 pi which you can again approximate using archimedes method.

Comment: This is true but the OP would like to know *why* that is.

Comment: Well than he is just asking why the inner product has a cosine in it.