# Connection between different types of "disjunctive" theorems

Tags: linear-algebra, soft-question, linear-transformations

While reviewing some linear algebra, I came across the well-known formula for two subspaces $X,Y$ of a vector space $V$:

$$\dim(X+Y)=\dim(X)+\dim(Y)-\dim(X \cap Y)$$

I've seen this formula many times, but this time it reminded me of the following from probability theory:

$$P(A \cup B)= P(A) + P(B) - P(A\cap B)$$

I thought this might be a coincidence, but then when I started thinking about it I also noted that in Boolean algebra, we have the identity:

$$ a \vee b = a + b - ab$$

Also, we have for two sets $A,B$:

$$|A \cup B|=|A|+|B|- |A \cap B|$$

Related to the law of cosines applied to higher dimensional vector spaces (thanks @EricNathanStucky):

$$|\mathbf{u}+\mathbf{v}|^2=|\mathbf{u}|^2+|\mathbf{v}|^2+2(\mathbf{u}\cdot\mathbf{v})$$

**Conjecture:** The general pattern appears to be:

Let $f$ be some functional $f:X \to \mathbb{R}$ over elements of a commutative ring $G:=(X,+,\cdot)$. Then for two elements $A,B\in X$ we have:

$$f(A+B) = f(A)+f(B) - f(A\cdot B)$$

Two questions:

1. Is this a coincidence or is there a more general theme here (e.g., like "[concentration of measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concentration_of_measure)")
2. I'm having trouble with a definition for $\cdot$ for vectors that satisfy my conjecture (maybe [likely] because I could be wrong ;-) - any suggestions?

Comment: For Boolean algebra, did you mean $a\color{red}\lor b= a+b-ab$?

Comment: If there is a general pattern, it’s probably related to category theory.

Comment: @J.W.Tanner yes

Comment: @user1551 I think that is probably true but I don't know enough category theory :)

Comment: Spitballing: I'm almost certain the keyword here is Möbius inversion (best seen on Wikipedia through the "incidence algebra" page) which generalizes inclusion-exclusion, of which here are many $n=2$ cases. Probability sits a bit uncomfortably in this scheme because it is only "locally locally finite", but that suffices for us. The law of cosines does have a "genuine" difference, though: the $2$ there arises from a lack of an absorption axiom in the underlying structure. It is possible that this can be explained by an appropriate category algebra, but I don't hear Möbius much in that context.

Comment: Fridge logic moment: Shouldn't that $-2$ be a $+2$? The proof of that is expanding $(\mathbf{u}+\mathbf{v})\cdot(\mathbf{u}+\mathbf{v})$, right? Very disturbing to me to think of subtraction as a disjunction, so I'm not sure my absorption comment makes any sense.

Comment: I agree with @EricNathanStucky : search the web for Mobius functions on partially ordered sets.

Comment: @EricNathanStucky -- I don't follow the -2 vs +2 -- this is just the law of cosines: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4142786/law-of-cosines-for-n-dimensional-vectors

Comment: @Annika: In the linked post, notice LHS says $b-a$.

Comment: @EricNathanStucky -- ah, good catch! I'll update my post :)

Comment: @EricNathanStucky -- although then this does mess up my little pattern/conjecture -- so may not be appropriate as part of my conjecture

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest explanation / generalization is probably with the concept of [measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Measure_(mathematics)).
The [page on inclusion-exclusion principle in nLab](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/inclusion-exclusion) explains it.

$\\$

Another explanation / generalization - which I like - is to use **multiplicities**, i.e. multisets; and some kind of linear forms.

Given a set $E$, let's define $M = \mathbb{Z} ^ E$. An element of $M$ is a vector of integers, one integer for each element of $E$.

On $\mathcal P (E)$, union and intersection are not group operations, rather $(\mathcal P (E), \cup)$ and $(\mathcal P (E), \cap)$ are idempotent monoids.
But $(M, +)$ is a group, and if we identify $\mathcal P (E)$ with vectors in $M$ whose coordinates are $0$ or $1$, union of independent elements of $\mathcal P (E)$ is equivalent to their addition in $M$, and union of non-independent elements of $\mathcal P (E)$ is $\max$ in $M$, coordinate-wise.

More precisely, if $a, b \in M$, we define $\max(a,b)$ and $\min(a,b)$ to mean: apply $\max$ and $\min$ coordinate-wise.
Then we have: $\max(a,b) + \min(a,b) = a + b$. This is true in $\mathbb Z$ so it is true in $M$.
And if $a$, $b$ are in $\mathcal P (E)$, i.e. vectors in $M$ whose coordinates are $0$ or $1$,
$a \cup b$ in $\mathcal P (E)$ $=$ $\max(a,b)$ in $M$, and
$a \cap b$ in $\mathcal P (E)$ $=$ $\min(a,b)$ in $M$.

So if $f: M \rightarrow \mathbb Z$ preserves addition, max and min (which I called "some kind of linear form" above - note that with an external multiplication by elements in $\mathbb Z$, $M$ is a module),
$f(\max(a,b)) + f(\min(a,b)) = f(a) + f(b)$,
$f(\max(a,b)) = f(a) + f(b) - f(\min(a,b))$

This translates into $f(a \cup b) = f(a) + f(b) - f(a \cap b)$ when $a, b \in \mathcal P (E)$.
It explains $|A \cup B|=|A|+|B|- |A \cap B|$: cardinal preserves addition (of multisets), max and min.
It also explains $P(A \cup B)= P(A) + P(B) - P(A\cap B)$ if we use $M = \mathbb{R} ^ E$.

For $\dim(X+Y)=\dim(X)+\dim(Y)-\dim(X \cap Y)$, we have to consider the $M$ of $E$ where $E$ is the base vectors of $X$ and $Y$ (chosen so that they include a base of $X \cap Y$).
Then:
$X+Y$ is $\max(X,Y)$ in $M$,
$\dim(X)+\dim(Y) = \dim(X \times Y)$, and $\times$ of vector subspaces is $+$ in $M$,
$X \cap Y$ is $\min$ in $M$.

$\\$

A further **generalization** may perhaps use **matroids**, as they generalize the concept of independent sets, and for independent sets we have $f(a \cup b) = f(a) + f(b)$. But I don't know if the full relation $f(a \cup b) = f(a) + f(b) - f(a \cap b)$ for non-independent sets can be reached using matroids only.

Comment: +1 Thank you for this answer — will take some time to digest but this looks very helpful :)